# netduino plus 2 compatible gps/gsm module

Tags: gps, gsm, netduino

I have a netduino plus 2 board and I am trying to send gps location with gprs to my server.I am a java programmer by profession,but recently I got interested in IoT and m2m communications.I would like to know if I can use the below shield for the netduino plus 2 , though its mentioned for arduino.I just want to make sure I purchase the right parts.Or if anyone could suggest me the right parts to purchase for my gps+gsm tracking project.

here is the shield which I found that has gps & gsm.

http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/GPS/GPRS/GSM_Module_V3.0_(SKU:TEL0051)

Comment: Generally the issues when using a shield with a non-ATMEGA Arduino-form-factor board are 1) Voltage level comptability, 2) Presence of peripherals on needed pins, though that can often be overcome by bit-banging, and 3) Software library support - especially when you are using an entirely different language / tooclhain.  Also, have you considered an older Android phone as a complete platform?

Comment: This is a good article about your topic http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/What-Is-an-Arduino-Shield-and-Why-Should-My-Netduino-Care

Answer (score 1):

I use a [GPRS Shield](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/gprs-shield-p-779.html) from SeeedStudio and the [GPS Shield](http://imall.iteadstudio.com/development-platform/im120417017.html) from Iteadstudio (Just need to change the serial ports used so they play nicely together)

I initially trialled the "Netduino Driver For SeeedStudio GSM Shield" on Codeplex but now use the CodeFreak Out SeeedStudio GPRS Driver which is available via NuGet or as source code on Github.

I use the NetMF Toolbox NMEA driver on codeplex with a couple of mods. When the serial port reports an error I flush the inbound buffer and I also return the Horizontal Dilution of position (hDoP)

(I would post the NuGet, GitHub & NetMF toolbox links but don't have enough reputation points)

Bryn @ devMobile

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Your answer seems to be a bit off-topic. The OP was asking about compatibility between a specific set of components. Please note also that this site is _not_ intended to offer advice regarding the purchase of commercial products, questions here should relate specifically to the _design_ of electronics.